# Vertical and horizontal headers for HTML table for JSON data

Tags: html, css, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I need to implement a table like this:

[image]

I'm hoping to add more functionality to the table like editing etc., so I'd like to use something like Angular UI Grid. The data for the table cells and headers comes in the form of a JSON from an API endpoint.

```
[{verticalHeader: "vertical", horizontalHeader: 'horizontal', value: 0.9}, ....]
```

The values for verticalHeader and horizontalHeader are unique.

Is there a way to have both type of headers? And how do I efficiently populate the table using the above JSON format. (100s of vertical headers but about 10-15 horizontal headers)

Angular UI Grid is not a must. I'm open to suggestions/other libraries as well. Thanks in advance.